# using ms access to update a local table without importing the whole list from sharepoint

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a bit of a dilema concerning a large database. I have a database where all the data is kept on a sharepoint server. The cache is cleared everytime database is closed.

My problem is that the parts number list is quite large (12200 records)  and needs to be cached fully every time access is open. This list however is fairly static so I want to make it static and simply run an update to apply changes that occured when the access app is opened.

I do not know how to do that, I know I can link the sharepoint list and simply update the local list with sql. This however defeats the purpose since access will have to first download the whole data from sharepoint to begin with.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what is so big the local table or the sharepoint linked tables.  Which is it you want to update?

Comment: they are both the same list. I want to check for differences between the sharepoint list and the local table and apply them to the local table

Comment: How long could be deleting local data and inserting sharepoint data at startup? 30 sec. is a reasonable period for ***INITIALIZING SYSTEM*** actions.

Comment: Just for the note: it takes me no longer than 2 sec. to synchronize or replace table data with data from files in a LAN drive, some 25K-40K records.

Comment: The problem is it takes roughly 30 secs to load up that one list every time. I don't know what your speed is. Data is in a sharepoint linked list, internet speed is roughly 10-15mbps I don't know if retrieving from sharepoint is so inefficient or what else could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to update the local table with the fresh data from the SharePoint table, you could create a query that simply overwrites the old table from the SharePoint Table.

For example:
After you link SharepointTableA, create a query

```
SELECT SharePointTableA.* INTO LocalTableB  FROM SharePointTableA
```

This will overwrite all the contents of the local table with the data from the SharePoint Table.

unless there's a specific reason why you don't want to overwrite records...

Comment: I know I can do that the problem is this will do exactly what I am trying to avoid which is to cache the entire sharepoint list first.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you don't want to cache the Entire list?